# how to update cell based on another autocomplete cell with Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handsontable

i am already have complete code to return autocomplete data and fill another cell based on this autocomplete 
but i want to make it dynamic from ajax request to database query.
how to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/wvXvJ/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var $container  = $("#mytables");
        var comsources  = ["Chrysler", "Nissan", "Suzuki", "Toyota"];

        var ac = [
            {"name":"Chrysler","label":"Pepsi Cola Hat","price":"24","abbrev":"CRY"},
            {"name":"Nissan","label":"Candle Lights Dinner","price":"780","abbrev":"NSS"},
            {"name":"Suzuki","label":"Pork Meat Ball","price":"178","abbrev":"SZK"},
            {"name":"Toyota","label":"Granny Health Supplement","price":"24","abbrev":"TYT"}
        ];

        var ht = $container.handsontable({
            startRows: 1,
            startCols: 5,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: ['Item Name', 'Price', 'Code'],
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "name",
                    type: 'autocomplete',
                    source: comsources,
                    strict: false
                },
                {
                    data: "price"
                },
                { 
                    data: "code"
                }
            ],
            afterChange : function(arr, op) {
                if(op=="edit"&&arr.length==1) {
                    var value = arr[0][3];
                    for(var i=0;i<ac.length;i++) {
                        if(ac[i].name == value) {
                            $container.handsontable("setDataAtCell", arr[0][0], 1, ac[i].price);
                            $container.handsontable("setDataAtCell", arr[0][0], 2, ac[i].abbrev);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have defined exactly how to do it in their [documentation](http://handsontable.com/demo/autocomplete.html#strict-ajax):

```
$("#example3").handsontable({
  data: getCarData(),
  startRows: 7,
  startCols: 4,
  colHeaders: ["Car", "Year", "Chassis color", "Bumper color"],
  columns: [
    {
      type: 'autocomplete',
      source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
          //url: 'php/cars.php', //commented out because our website is hosted on static GitHub Pages
          url: 'json/autocomplete.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            query: query
          },
          success: function (response) {
              console.log("response", response);
              //process(JSON.parse(response.data)); //JSON.parse takes string as a argument
              process(response.data);

          }
        });
      },
      strict: true
    },
    {} /*Year is a default text column*/,
    {} /*Chassis color is a default text column*/,
    {} /*Bumper color is a default text column*/
  ]
});
```

Comment: I think what the author wants to do is update the other columns once the user has selected the column that has autocomplete. e.g (Set the item name and set the column for abbrv and price)